# WPF Editable ComboBox validation

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm

What I want to accomplish is to be able to validate for new category typed into the editable combobox or for one to be selected from existing combobox'es list of categories.

The validation works for selectedItem only, not for new text entered into Text. As soon as I add the `ValidateOnDataErrors="True"` to ComboBox'es Text property, events from entering new text are not firing. Category is a simple object with Id and Name.

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationErrorTamplate">
        <Border BorderBrush="DodgerBlue" BorderThickness="0.75">
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="ElementInError" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<ComboBox Name="CbCategory"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          IsEditable="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory,
                                 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                 ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
          Style="{StaticResource ElementInError}"
          Text="{Binding NewCategory.Name,
                         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                         ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
          Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ValidationErrorTamplate}" />
```

ViewModel: (`: IDataErrorInfo`)

```
    private Category _newCategory;
    private Category _selectedCategory;

    public ExpenseCategory SelectedCategory
    {
       get { return _selectedCategory; }
       set
           {
              if (Equals(_selectedCategory, value)) return;
              _selectedCategory = value;
              SendPropertyChanged("SelectedCategory");
            }
     }
     public ExpenseCategory NewExpenseCategory
     {
        get { return _newExpenseCategory ?? (_newExpenseCategory = new ExpenseCategory()); }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(_newExpenseCategory, value)) return;
                _newExpenseCategory = value;
                SendPropertyChanged("NewExpenseCategory");
            }
        }

public string this[string propertyName]
        {
            get
            {
                switch (propertyName)
                {
                    case "SelectedExpenseCategory":
                    case "NewExpenseCategory":
                        {
                            if ((SelectedCategory == null) || (NewCategory == null)
                            {
                                return "Category must be selected or entered";
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return string.Empty;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working, it's may be not the superb way, but it gets the job done.

What I basically did, I changed the NewCategory to be a string, not object of type Category. When the user populates new value into the combobox it initiates a new SelectedCategory based on a value passed into the NewCategory constructor. It doesn't work if I keep the NewCategory of object type Category.

```
   public string NewExpenseCategory
    {
        get { return _newExpenseCategory ?? (_newExpenseCategory = ""); }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(_newExpenseCategory, value)) 
                return;
            _newExpenseCategory = value;
            SendPropertyChanged("NewExpenseCategory");
            SelectedExpenseCategory = new ExpenseCategory
                {
                    Name = value
                };
        }
    }

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (propertyName)
            {
                case "SelectedExpenseCategory":
                case "NewExpenseCategory":
                    {
                        if ((SelectedExpenseCategory.Name.Length == 0) && (NewExpenseCategory.Length == 0))
                        {
                            return "Category must be selected or entered";
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I always get a null error when I try to type a new value in to my combobox for the 'Current' item.  Care to supply the Current item code with what you have as well?  It fails on my line that is equivelant to your (SelectedExpenseCategory.Name.Length == 0)